# Prove or disprove: the average of any two odd integers is always odd

Tags: solution-verification, parity

Prove or disprove the following statement: *the average of any two odd integers is always odd*.

The proof that this statement is false is given below. Please, verify whether the one is valid or not.

$\mathrm{(I)}$ Formal restatement of the problem: $$\forall m, n \in \mathbb{Z}, m\ and\ n\ are\ odd\ \rightarrow \frac{m + n}{2}\ is\ odd.$$

$\mathrm{(II)}$ Proof that this statement is true for some odd integers. More precisely, when two odd integers are equal.

$$\frac{(2k + 1) + (2k + 1)}{2};$$
$$\frac{4k + 2}{2};$$
$$\frac{2(2k + 1)}{2};$$
$$2k + 1.$$

$2k + 1$ is odd by definition, so we proved that the statement $\mathrm{(I)}$ is true for some odd integers.

$\mathrm{(III)}$ Now let us consider the case when two odd integers are not equal. Let $2k + 1$ represent the first odd integer and $2r + 1$ represent the second one.

We want to show that their average is equal to yet another odd integer which we will denote as $2s + 1$.

$$\frac{(2k + 1) + (2r + 1)}{2} = 2s + 1;$$
$$\frac{2k + 2r + 2}{2} = 2s + 1;$$
$$\frac{2(k + r + 1)}{2} = 2s + 1;$$
$$k + r + 1 = 2s + 1;$$
$$k + r = 2s;$$
$$s = \frac{k + r}{2}.$$

By definition of an odd number, $s$ must belong to $\mathbb{Z}$, but that's not always the case since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not closed under division. For example, if $k = 1$ and $r = 2$, then $s = 1.5$ and $s \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

The statement $\mathrm{(I)}$ is false since it is not true for all odd numbers.

Q.E.D.

Comment: A single counterexample is all you need...Like maybe $1$ and $3$?

Comment: All your argument does is to take the long way round to a simple counterexample...which you could have written down at the start.  Your choice of $(k,r)=(1,2)$ translates to the counterexample $3,5$ which is fine.  The rest of the discussion isn't needed.  If you want a general "classification"  try to prove that all odd numbers are either $1$ or $-1$ $\pmod 4$ and the average of two is even if and only you are averaging one of each.

Answer (score 1):

To *disprove* the statement, it is enough to produce a single counterexample, rather than a family of counterexamples (as you do in your post - this is overkill and does not add anything to the proof.) For a quick counterexample, the average of $1$ and $3$ is $\frac{1+3}{2} = 2$ which is even.

Answer (score 0):

Let $4k+1$ and $4t+3$, $k,t \in Z$ be two odd integers of the form.

$\text{average}=\frac{(4k+1)+(4t+3)}{2}=2(k+t+1)$ is an even number.

The assumption is not true for all pairs of odd numbers.